# Procedure For Get String And insert , In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have Two Tables
first :

```
CREATE TABLE z_names (ID number,
                  NAME VARCHAR2(200))
```

Second:

```
 CREATE TABLE Z_FNAME 
         ("FAMILY" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
      "ID" NUMBER, 
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
      "NAME_ID" NUMBER
            )
```

How **Write Procedure for Insert Into Second Table** By String ,With This Conditions :
1- Example Of input String : *nam1;fam1,nam2;fam2* => nam1 Insert Into **NAME** Column And fam1 Into **FAMILY**
2-**ID** Generated By Trigger I Have Writed Before
3-**NAME_ID** Comes From FIRST table

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; the complete setup code, so if you have a "Generated By Trigger I Have Writed Before" then include the trigger; details of the expected input to the procedure; the expected output for that input; and details of edge cases. StackOverflow is not a code writing service where we do your homework for you. You need to put the effort in to have made an attempt first and then we can help to debug it.

Comment: Why are you storing `NAME` in both tables? The `ID` in which table is "Generated By Trigger I Have Writed Before"? What is the relationship between the `z_fname` table and the `fnames` table? What happens if you get a `name` where a corresponding row does not exist in the `z_names` table? How many parameters so you expect your procedure to take? Is it 1 delimited string that you need to split into many name/family pairs? Is it always 1 string containing two name/family pairs? Is it 4 parameters? Or something else?

Comment: It would be much easier and more efficient to use a supported format like JSON or XML rather than a custom string format like `nam1;fam1,nam2;fam2`.

Comment: Instead of developing convoluted solutions you should use prepared statement and pass individual values via bind variables. What you try to achieve is not how DBMS is intended to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a table you previously created (I remember that question so I reused it, as well as the sequence), you'd split input string into rows and fetch names, somehow; I chose regular expressions, presuming that names consist of only one word.

Table with names (inserted previously):

```
SQL> select * From z_names;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 john
         2 jim
         3 jack
```

Procedure expects that strings you're passing as parameters contain `name` which is already inserted into the `z_names` table.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_string in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into z_fname (family, id, name, name_id)
  4    with temp as
  5      (select regexp_substr(par_string, '[^,]+', 1, level) nf
  6       from dual
  7       connect by level <= regexp_count(par_string, ',') + 1
  8      )
  9    select regexp_substr(t.nf, '\w+', 1, 2) family,
 10           z_names_seq.nextval id,
 11           regexp_substr(t.nf, '\w+', 1, 1) name,
 12           n.id
 13    from temp t join z_names n on n.name = regexp_substr(t.nf, '\w+', 1, 1);
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test('john;Little,jack;Foot,jim;Bigfoot');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from z_fname;

FAMILY             ID NAME                    NAME_ID
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
Little             10 john                          1
Bigfoot            11 jim                           2
Foot               12 jack                          3

SQL>
```

---

However, from my point of view, that's somewhat awkward approach.  I don't know what tables you use in this *exercise* represent, but I'd expect them to be related to each other (via referential integrity constraint). It also means that `z_fname` most probably isn't normalized - you would store only the foreign key constraint value which points to the master table (`z_names`), not store both `name` AND `id`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a template and you should scheck it and modify as you want (that's all what i can do with all data than you give me):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_name
(name_in IN varchar2, fam_in IN varchar2)
IS
 max_id_names number; --variable for max id  from z_names and new name
 max_id_fam number; --variable for max id  from Z_FNAME
BEGIN

--1. Find max id from "ID Generated By Trigger I Have Writed Before" and SET IT TO max_id_names

   INSERT INTO z_names 
    (
        max_id_names,
        NAME 
    )
   VALUES
    ( 
       :max_id_names,  --you will find it
       name_in -- IN param
    );


--2. Find max id from "ID Generated By Trigger I Have Writed Before" and SET IT TO max_id_fam 
    INSERT INTO Z_FNAME 
    ( 
       FAMILY,
       ID,
       NAME,
       NAME_ID
    )
   VALUES
    ( 
        fam_in, -- IN param
        :max_id_fam,  -- you will find it 
        name_in, --IN param
        :max_id_names --you already have it because you inserted the names 
    );
END;
/
```